# how to get paramaters of my policy assignment

Tags: azure, powershell

```
$test=Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/$subs" -Pre  -DefaultProfile $rest  -PolicyDefinitionId $Policy.PolicyDefinitionId -Verbose
```

it returns all the information other than the parameters ( allowed tag , values) and I need this information to anather feature

Thanks

Comment: usually to get something, you need to use the `get` verb, not the `set` verb

Comment: Have you tried the `-IncludeDescendent` switch?

Comment: You can use REST API for getting parameters - GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/{policyDefinitionName}?api-version=2018-05-01

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API for getting parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/policydefinitions/get

Answer (score 0):

For this PowerShell command, you can use it to get all the policy assignments, no matter which policy and which resource like this:

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment
```

And you also can use it to get a special policy assignment for a special resource like this:

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Scope resourceId -PolicyDefinitionId policyDefinitionId
```

See the examples in [Get-AzPolicyAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-2.4.0). If you want to get the policy definitions, you can use the PowerShell command [Get-AzPolicyDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicydefinition?view=azps-2.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

After assigning $test with Get-AzPolicyAssignment

Do the following -

```
($test).Properties.Parameters
```

Will return the parameters e.g - of an output

```
listOfRegionsWhereNetworkWatcherShouldBeEnabled
-----------------------------------------------
@{value=System.Object[]}
```

You can further drill in the parameter like this

```
($test).Properties.Parameters.listOfRegionsWhereNetworkWatcherShouldBeEnabled
```

Will finally return

```
value
-----
{northeurope, westeurope}
```